# How to append columns of a pandas Dataframe based on none/null values?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, null, python-3.6, nan

Need your help on one issue.
I have a dataframe `df` which has 3 columns of 'object' data type- `opt1`,`opt2`,`opt3`.

Now I need to create a new column `var` which will have followings-

1. if `opt2` and `opt3` are None/Null/Empty and `opt1` is not None/Null/Empty: 
   then `df['var'] = df['opt1']`
2. elif `opt1` and `opt3` are None/Null/Empty and `opt2` is None/Null/Empty:
   then `df['var'] = df['opt1'] + '|' + df['opt3']`
3. elif `opt1` and `opt2` are None/Null/Empty and `opt3` is None/Null/Empty:
   then `df['var'] = df['opt1'] + '|' + df['opt2']`
4. else: `df['var'] = df['opt1'] + '|' + df['opt2'] + '|' + df['opt3']`

Please suggest me to put above conditions in Python 3.6 or share me any better approach.

Comment: Your point 2 and 3 is missing some `"not"`s...

Comment: Actually I am unable to design a correct if-elif-else condition for this scenario, this snippet is only for understanding my test cases. If possible please share the correct version of whole condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'opt1':['',np.nan,'a','a','a',np.nan],
                       'opt2':[np.nan,'b',np.nan,'b','b',np.nan],
                        'opt3':['c','Null',np.nan,'c',np.nan,np.nan]})

print (df)
  opt1 opt2  opt3
0       NaN     c
1  NaN    b  Null
2    a  NaN   NaN
3    a    b     c
4    a    b   NaN
5  NaN  NaN   NaN

#replace strings Null and empty strins to NaN 
df1 = df.mask(df.isin(['Null','']))
#join values per rows with filter out NaNs
df['var'] = df1.apply(lambda x: '|'.join(x.dropna()), 1)
print (df)
  opt1 opt2  opt3    var
0       NaN     c      c
1  NaN    b  Null      b
2    a  NaN   NaN      a
3    a    b     c  a|b|c
4    a    b   NaN    a|b
5  NaN  NaN   NaN
```

Comment: df['var'] = df.apply(lambda x: '|'.join(x.dropna()), 1) it gives me error-KeyError: "['opt1' 'opt2' 'opt3'] not in index"

Comment: currently in opt1 there are values but in other two columns values are as None. But I cannot remove these two columns because in future they may have data.

Comment: It remove dynamically - only if `None` or `NaN`, else not.

Comment: Instead of Nan or Null, opt2 and opt3 columns have None. Will this work for this also? Because I am getting KeyError: "['opt1' 'opt2' 'opt3'] not in index"

Comment: Yes, dropna remove `None` and `NaN` if both missing values. If `None` is string, need `df1 = df.mask(df.isin(['Null','', 'None']))`